# How to fix my CSS and make my site look blog- or magazine-like?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This is the code for my site, CSS is as `<style></style>` even though it's as an external stylesheet in the original basically:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="magazinetheme.css">
```

This is the code:

```html
<TITLE>A Guide Book on Tourism</TITLE>
<style>
  div {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 300px;
    border: 5.2px solid green;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 25px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: left;
  }
  .div1 {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 500px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: auto;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 25px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
  }

  .div2 {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 300px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 25px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
  }

  img.auto {
    width: 425px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .datetime {
    font-style: oblique;
  }
  .wv {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
<div>
</div>
<div class="div1">

  <article><H1>My page</H1>
    <p><span class="datetime">02 Jul 2016</span></p>
    <section class="wv"><img class="auto" src="placeholderpic.jpg"></section>
  </article>
  <p>Your text here</p>
</div>
<div class="div2">
</div>
```

The CSS works well - but I want to add a header, and generally have CSS more like this site: [with links in header and a menu](http://www.autocarindia.com/auto-news/ford-mustang-india-launch-on-july-13-2016-402469.aspx).

How can I improve my CSS to create a menu/header that can have a dropdown with some basic JavaScript and is compatible with older browsers? [I have User Agent Switcher on Firefox for testing, on OS X El Capitan 10.11.5].

I had considered jQuery, but am not sure if it is suited to older browsers.

Basically - I want to fix my layout and make it look more blog or magazine-like whilst retaining backward-compatibility for older browsers across Windows, Linux and Mac OS X. This is for a PHP based site but it is a template/layout I have created independently; the PHP blog is one I have been working on from a basic website tutorial on creating your own PHP blog.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you've provided I would recommend you look into a platform like [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) and then look for a free theme that is close to the look you are going for to just tweak to what fits you best.

Comment: @avenas8808 Please accept an answer or communicate that neither answers are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use either one of these solutions:

1. Keep your site on your own PHP backend and use some sort of CSS framework. We're exploding with those in the last years - [Twitter's Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)'s many favorites, my personal opinion goes for [ZURB's Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) - and there are many more options.
2. move your site to a WordPress theme - there are many free & paid tutorials on converting an HTML page to WP theme - and from there the skys will be your limit.

Each of the options can give you the tools to customize your site to a Blog / Magazine like. the difference is on the back-end.

Enjoy your exploring!